# `sap.m.HeaderContainer` triggers rendering twice

Tags: sapui5

Why are the rendering events of the view (such as `onBeforeRendering` and `onAfterRendering`) in the *scenario 1* triggered twice?

### *Scenario 1*

#### `Sample.view.xml`

```xml
<mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  xmlns="sap.m"
  controllerName="my.controller.Sample">
  <Page id="EmpStat" showHeader="false">
    <HeaderContainer>
      <!-- ... -->
    </HeaderContainer>
  </Page>
</mvc:View>
```

#### `Sample.controller.js`

```js
onAfterRendering: function() {
  alert("Test"); // called twice
},
```

### *Scenario 2*

#### `Sample.view.xml`

```xml
<mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  xmlns:layout="sap.ui.layout"
  xmlns="sap.m"
  controllerName="my.controller.Sample">
  <Page>
    <!-- No <HeaderContainer> -->
    <layout:Grid>
      <!-- ... -->
    </layout:Grid>
  </Page>
</mvc:View>
```

#### `Sample.controller.js`

```js
onAfterRendering: function() {
  alert("Test"); // called once.
},
```

Comment: It was a bug in the framework. It's no longer reproducible. See https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/3250.

Answer (score -1):

**HeaderContainer has a borrowed class onAfterRendering from sap.ui.core.control, hence in scenario one headerContainer calls this method once and sap.m.Page calls the method another time.**
The only way is it to handle the scenario is bypassing the execution of your code a second time either by using event parent source check or by using the logic I have given below as in most of the cases the event gets called only twice.

You can create a counter in onInit() and then update the value in onAfterRendering() and execute the corresponding code only when the condition is matched with the counter value.

```
onInit:function(){
   this.afterRenderingCount = 0;
}, 

onAfterRendering: function (oEvent) {
    if(this.afterRenderingCount === 1){
        this.afterRenderingCount =0;
        //method call
        this.exampleMethod();
     }
    this.afterRenderingCount++;
}
```

Comment: From the application's point of view, it's unfortunately not that easily predictable how many times the view or control renders since rendering is not the responsibility of the application developer. Please don't simply rely on a counter like this. Try to find a possible cause of the behavior instead of fighting the symptom awkwardly. IMHO, application code shouldn't rely on rendering and other DOM behaviors at all.

Comment: HeaderContainer has a borrowed class onAfterRendering from sap.ui.core.control, hence in scenario one headerContainer calls this method once and sap.m.Page calls the method another time. So it is neither a bug nor a thing that needs to be cured. It is the way in which sapui5 behaves. The only way is it to handle the scenario is bypassing the execution of your code a second time either by using event parent source check or by using the logic I have given above as in most of the cases the event gets called only twice. Please judge the answer before downvoting and appreciate if you could upvote.

Comment: As discussed at https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/3250, the invalidation process of `sap.m.HeaderContainer` is fixed now. Your assumed cause and the proposed solution made in this answer are simply wrong. As the issue is no longer reproducible (`HeaderContainer` no longer triggers `onAfterRendering` of the view twice), please delete this answer to avoid encouraging such anti-patterns (relying on the call counter).